# IS there any way to get redirected to view of a mvc project from another mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

We have implanted 2 utilities using mvc. And both utilities have authentication using Active directory.We are using single sign on here,means if the user authenticated in 1st application then he can access 2nd application without entering credentials in 2nd application.

Question:If user is not Authenticated in 1st application and he is trying to access the dashboard of second application then he must be redirected to login page of 1st application....IS there any way to do this?

Comment: This can be configured in your web.config or somewhere in code. Just set the login page to be the one in your first application.

Comment: <forms name=".ADAuth" loginUrl="http://localhost:12345/" timeout="45" requireSSL="false" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All"/> I did this but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved :)
  return Redirect("http://localhost:12350/");
It is working.